# Is training required under §61.55 to move from PIC to SIC?

Tags: faa-regulations, flight-training, currency, logbook-endorsements

I am current as PIC in type on a jet requiring two crew members. I will be out of currency as PIC soon and my company wants me to move to SIC position when that happens.

Am I required to have training specified under [14 CFR 61.55](http://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/61.55) for SIC if I am already type rated in the aircraft?

Comment: I can't imagine that you do, but can you be more specific about which part of 61.55 you think is in question?

Comment: I can't imagine I do either, but none of 61.55 addresses it and its vague as well.

Answer (score 7):

No training needed.  If you are typed in the aircraft, none of the SIC type stuff applies (that is just an ICAO formality and is superseded by having a normal type rating).  As long as you meet the requirements to act as SIC (landing currency, company training currency, etc) you are good to transition to the right seat with no additional training.

Comment: This is an old answer, but it was linked to from another question and I realized that 61.55 isn't **only** for the SIC type, but 61.55(a) & (b) refer to SIC currency.  An SIC is still required to be current and it isn't clear whether a&b refer to someone who is moving from PIC to SIC and has never logged the 61.55 training.